# Difference between "This URL" and "Origin" toggle

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to resolve a bad page score using https://pagespeed.web.dev/
On the top part ("Discover what your real users are experiencing") there's a toggle button to choose "This URL" and "Origin", and somehow the values in "This URL" is much worse than "Origin" (which relatively match what I got if using Chrome Dev Tool)

So could somebody please enlighten me what's the difference between those two / how Page Insight got those 2 from, as well as the difference between those and the "Diagnose performance issues" section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top part of the report comes from real users visiting your site, while the lower part is a single simulated test of the URL you are interested in.

"This URL" is the metrics for the URL you are interested in, and "Origin" is the averages for the whole site.

So this sounds like your test URL performs worse than average.